# Redirecting nonexistent index.html to home page in Wordpress is causing too many redirects in browser

Tags: html, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I recently changed my website from static html to Wordpress, and in doing so I've been redirecting all of my former and nonexistent pages with my .htaccess file whenever Google shows me a crawl error. I've been successful in redirecting all crawl errors until today. My old `index.html` is throwing a crawl error and when I use:

```
Redirect 301 /index.html http://www.example.com
```

... I get this from my browser:

> Too many redirects occurred trying to open www.example.com. This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another page which then is redirected to open the original page.*

I have since removed the above redirect from my `.htaccess` file and will just live with the crawl error if I can't get this resolved. But I'm thinking somebody knows how to solve this and if so, I'd really appreciate it if you'd let me know how.

Comment: do u have any other redirects in htaccess

Comment: What is directory index file now?

Comment: Yes, like I said in my original post, "I've been redirecting all of my former and nonexistent pages with my .htaccess file whenever Google shows me a crawl error. I've been successful in redirecting all crawl errors until today." When I go into my Google Webmaster account and click on the crawl error it takes me to a page on my site that says "Page Not Found." With all other crawl errors I've had in the past I simply used my .htaccess file to redirect the crawl error link to the page I wanted it to go to & that fixed it. Not so with this error. It appears index has to be handled differently.

Comment: What is directory index file now? I'm not sure I know what you're asking. My website is built on the Wordpress platform. There is an index.php file in the root directory, but that is not my home page like my old index.html file was on my old site. I'm thinking my home page is being pulled from several different templates as well as a database. Wordpress is a new world for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could experience this redirect loop if your `DirectoryIndex` is set to `index.html` (as the first option), which is likely to be the default setting on your server.

Basically, when you access a directory, eg. `http://example.com/` (the root directory) then the `DirectoryIndex` directive tells the server which file to serve (via an internal rewrite). eg. `http://example.com/index.html`. This then seeds the redirect loop.

Since you are using WordPress, you could change this in .htaccess to favour `index.php` instead. For example, at the top of your .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

However, you could also solve this by using mod_rewrite (which is probably preferable). In fact, since WordPress already uses mod_rewrite (eg. `RewriteRule` directive) then you should also be using mod_rewrite for your redirects, not mod_alias (eg. `Redirect` directive). You should not mix redirects from both modules in .htaccess since you can easily get conflicts. Different modules execute at different times, regardless of their order in .htaccess.

By using mod_rewrite you can avoid a redirect loop by checking against `THE_REQUEST`. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks w3d, your mod_rewrite you posted above fixed my error!